# Gene Sequencing and Plasmapper

Tags: dna-sequence

Is there anything similar to "http://www.addgene.org/browse/sequence/13846/" in Java (especially the circular map sequencing along with hover effect) ? 
For information I would like to convey that I am using Plasmapper and BioJava for achieving this, but, as the output is in image format, so I am not able to achieve the above said requirement.
Thanks...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Hello Roger. The intent for asking this question is to get any information related to bio-informatics. If it seems that it is not as per the topics of Stack Overflow, then please let me know where to publish this question...

Comment: Maybe the [biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com/) site would be better? It has tags for bioinformatics, but your question here seems to be off topic because it does not relate to a programming problem.

Comment: fine. Thanks for the needful suggestion.